# Laravel Define foreign key in relationship according to column value

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I'm having these relationships in my event Mode

```
public function invited()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'invitee');
    }

        public function senter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'invitor');
    }
```

Table will be having feild "**invitee**,**invitor** and **organiser**". My requirement is to have a method users() where foreign key for belongsTo will be "**invitee**" if "**organiser**" != "**invitee**" else foreign key should be **invitor**

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Augusto Moura, but I have found another solution and it's actually not the best one, but works for me, this way I can call users from event model, and also in call users as a nested relation.

```
    public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Invitation', 'round_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'round_invitations.round_id', 'round_invitations.accept_status', 'round_invitations.reservation', 'round_invitations.id as request_id', 'users.id as user_id')
        ->join('users', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'round_invitations.invitee')->whereColumn('users.id', 'round_invitations.invitee');
            $join->orOn('users.id', '=', 'round_invitations.invitor')->whereColumn('users.id', 'round_invitations.invitor');

        })->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('accept_status', 1)->orWhere('reservation', 1);
    })->where('accept_status', '!=', 2)
        ->groupBy('round_invitations.id')
        ->whereColumn('users.id', '!=', 'organiser_id')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->distinct('users.id');
}

Usage example: Event::with('user')->find(2);
Another example: Organiser::with('Events.user')->find(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this `user()` you seek is derived from other relations, maybe it would be a good idea to make it a plain method (as opposed to a relation) or attribute.

**Plain method approach**

```
public function user(){
    if($this->organiser->id == $this->invited->id){
        return $this->invited;
    }
    else{
        return $this->senter;
    }
}
```

Usage example: `Event::with('organizer', 'invited', 'senter')->find(2)->user();`

**Attribute approach**

```
public function getUserAttribute(){
    if($this->organiser->id == $this->invited->id){
        return $this->invited;
    }
    else{
        return $this->senter;
    }
}
```

Usage example: `Event::with('organizer', 'invited', 'senter')->find(2)->user;`

Comment: Sorry but this approach won't work for me, because I want call users as a nested relationship